# How to display 500 error in browser while developing OpenCart

Tags: php, apache, debugging, opencart, http-status-code-500

I have just faced with problem, I made a mistake in `php` file and got 500 error.

The error was

```
[Tue Nov 08 18:07:14.165444 2016] [:error] [pid 1941] [client 192.168.0.1:53549] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in /var/www/store/catalog/controller/feed/rest_api.php on line 44
```

In `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

So my question if it is possible to display such errors in browser instead of just logging into error file ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. You should include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read How to Ask.

Answer (score 1):

This usually works for me:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this doesn't work, I've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`, provided that using `ini_set` is not disabled by PHP configuration.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this doesn't work, I've already tried.

Comment: @fyfdzbgz You would then need to make the change in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) or perhaps a .htacccess file. Unfortunately you cannot use a custom error handler to handle parse errors.